# How can I scan for library dependencies automatically given the source tree?

Tags: c, linux, deployment, dependencies

I'm working on building a very minimal nfs root for a Xen Dom0 host, booted through pxe.

It requires all the xen tools to be installed.  I haven't found a list anywhere but there are some indications by what packages people install to compile the hypervisor from scratch.  However, much of that is for building xen, not post build.

I know there are tools around to scan running programs for library dependencies, but many of the xen tools are utilities that only run occasionally, and there are many.

Other than the very time consuming manual or trial and error approach,  are there any development tools available under linux to scan the source files and/or compiled binaries to build up a list of dependencies?

If not, I suppose grepping for -ld might be a start in the Makefiles.  What makes it harder is that Xen uses other languages like python and ocaml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running `ldd` on compiled binaries on Linux will give you a list of required dynamic libraries.

Comment: And since this helped me find this: http://sourceforge.net/projects/recursive-ldd  I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps compiling using [SCons](http://www.scons.org/) with verbose output may be of some help